# Disable full-screen on iOS Flex 4.6 using Adobe Air 3.4

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, flex4, flex4.6

I'm creating a FLEX app for iOS and Android. To be able to use Higher Resolution icons for the app, I had to include Adobe Air 3.4 in FLEX 4.6 SDK (default is 3.1). Everything seems to work like charm exept I can't disable full-screen app on iOS.

Here is how it looks like right now:

[image]

Here is the code from configuration-app.xml file:

```
<initialWindow>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <aspectRatio>portrait</aspectRatio>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
    <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <softKeyboardBehavior>none</softKeyboardBehavior>
</initialWindow>
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way iOS 7 works. It is a feature, not a bug. You have two options:

1. Create a skin for `ViewNavigator` that detects if it is on iOS 7+ and pushes the content area down 40px (for iPhone. Not sure if it is different on iPad).
2. Upgrade to Flex 4.12 which introduced a CSS style, and OS and version specific media queries to get around this.

Additionally, you are going to want to upgrade AIR. 3.4, besides being close to 2 years old, will not be accepted by the App Store. To get your app into the app store, you need to be on at least 4.0 (which added support for XCode 5, which Apple began requiring in February). For the record, AIR is currently on version 13.0 (after 4.0, the number was bumped to match the Flash Player version)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That's really bad news since I can't use anything except Flex 4.6. If I upgrade to AIR 13, do I need to change something in my Flex code?

Comment: @Ivan No, just make sure to back up and look up overlaying the AIR SDK. Anyway, you can still make a `ViewNavigator` skin to do what the CSS style does. Is there a reason you have to use 4.6, though? You shouldn't have any issues upgrading to 4.12 and it should help with performance since a lot of what Apache has done since getting Flex (they've developed it since 4.7) is optimize it for mobile.

Comment: I'm just scared of updating it to 4.12 because the whole project I've inherited was done in 4.6. You say I won't have much problems with upgrading it? Thank you on your response!

Comment: @Ivan Try updating. Worst case, you find issues and revert back. Apache hasn't broken anything backwards-compatibility related, so I think you should be fine. Obviously you will want to test it well, but it should help your project run better on mobile devices if you upgrade